# How to cast an integer value to a type with double width?

Tags: c++, templates, integer-overflow

Sometimes I need to perform **intermediate** calculations with double-size values, for example - in this function, which returns a product of two numbers by modulo `m`:

```
template <typename T, typename DT>
T multiply(T x, T y, T mod)
{
  return (static_cast<DT>(x % mod) * (y % mod)) % mod;
}
```

This casting will be necessary if the `mod` value is close enough to the maximal value of the type `T`. As a result I have to call this function with **two** template parameters:

```
z = multiply<int32_t, int64_t>(x, y, m)
```

This looks ugly, and *is* error-prone. Is it any way to **automatically** declare the double-sized type `DT` (corresponding to the type `T`) inside such a function?

Also I see [this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0103r1.html#Revisions) document, which is supposed to solve this problem, but I couldn't find any info about its implementation in any popular C++ compiler.

Comment: `template<typename T> struct doublesize; template<> struct doublesize<int32_t> { using type = int64_t; };` and repeat for the other types you want to double. Then do `template<typename T> T multiple(T x, T y, T mod) { using DT = typename doublesize<T>::type; return (static_cast<DT>(x % mod) * (y % mod)) % mod; }`

Comment: sample implementation: https://github.com/viboes/std-make/blob/b498cd1c9468445781afdd3a9eafad9cb2efb96c/include/experimental/numerics/v1/numbers/double_wide_arithmetic.hpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing why you want exactly double-sized type, but provided you consider only signed and unsigned integrals, you can just pick the max-size compatible type for the calculations:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T multiply(T x, T y, T mod) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>, "Only integral types are expected");

    using CT = std::conditional_t<std::is_signed_v<T>, long long,
        std::conditional_t<std::is_unsigned_v<T>, unsigned long long, T>>;
    return (static_cast<CT>(x % mod) * (y % mod)) % mod;
}
```